# PHP - How to check a subfolder for a single file?

Tags: php, file-exists

```
    $code="524";
    $filepath="/assets/$code/";
    $file="";
    if(@fopen($path,"r")){

        // code
// replace function here (ill do this)

    }

echo '<a href="link.php?go=$file">your colour is: </a>';
```

- /assets/542
- /assets/542_blush/
- /assets/542_blush/542_blush.jpg

At the moment, the code is always going to be 3 digits, it will always have a subfolder with only an underscore and color and then inside that one file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has a [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function;

```
if ( file_exists( '/assets/' . $code . '_blush/' . $code . '_blush.jpg' ) ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I can't use file_exists as it is on a URL, so I am using fopen and also @fopen for my own error use - problem is, the subfolder may not be _blush, it may be read or green and it is always 123, then 123_color, then 123_color.jpg within the sub..